# Counting in how many rows do a pair of values occur

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, count, apply

my data frame looks like this:

```
Index   V1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6

 1      a    b  c   d    e  f

 2      b    c  d   e       
 3      a    b  c   f    g  
 4      a    c  f   d    g  
 5      b    c  d   g    h  i
 .      .    .  .   .    .  .
 .      .    .  .   .    .  .
```

I need to iterate through each row in the data frame and pick up pairs that appear together, and count them. For example a and b appears in row index 1 and 3, so count = 2.

Data frame has 6 columns excluding index and 554 rows. 6 variables in each row out of a possible 11.

First step would be to do the pair of a and b.

Then to do all combinations. eg. `a+c`, `a+d`, `a+e...` `b+c`, `b+d...`

I've used `table(apply(df,1,function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse='-')))` 
and 
`count(df)` from the `plyr` package but the output was freq of `a+b`, `a+b+c....` `b+c`, `b+c+d`.

I need freq of all pairs. So the freq of `a+b = (freq of a+b) + (freq of a+b+c) + (freq of a+b+c+d)` and so on

In excel, I've tried `COUNTIF`. Such that `COUNTIF(column1,a,column2,b)`, but a and b aren't always in columns 1 and 2 respectively.

Also tried `COUNTIF(df,a,df,b)` but that gave me a huge number.

Can be done in either r or excel. Although I think it would be faster in R.

Comment: Do you have a problem with your code? We can only help with your code if we can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an example random data,
let's assume that the data frame is in `C5:H558`.

Define a name `str` as

```
=$C$5:$C$558&$D$5:$D$558&$E$5:$E$558&$F$5:$F$558&$G$5:$G$558&$H$5:$H$558
```

Enter the symbols in `L5:V5` as well as in `K6:K16`.

Enter this counting formula

```
=IF(CODE($K7)>CODE(L$5),SUMPRODUCT(1-N(ISERROR(FIND($K7,str))+N(ISERROR(FIND(L$5,str)))>0)),"")
```

in `L6` and copy it to fill the rest of the table `L6:V16`.

[image]

Comment: hi, followed these steps exactly but theres no output. Can I clarify some points with you?
=IF(CODE($K7)>CODE(L$5),SUMPRODUCT(1-N(ISERROR(FIND($K7,str))+N(ISERROR(FIND(L$5,str)))>0)),"")

change k7 to k6 to put into L6?

the name df doesnt need to be called?

Thanks

Comment: @alexander wong: typo: the name used in the formula is the same that was defined.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for the prompt reply. Also, should there be $ signs in the str name?

Comment: @alexander wong: right, there should be $ signs, edited. Hope this helps.